# Color.FromNonPremultiplied different tinting with BlendState.NonPremultiplied

Tags: colors, xna, alphablending, premultiplied-alpha

In my XNA project I use non-processed images and draw them with `BlendState.NonPremultiplied` so they look normal around the edges. But when I use non-white color (`Color.FromNonPremultiplied(12, 34, 56, 78)`) in `SpriteBatch.Draw` method, it doesn't tint the sprite as it would if the `BlendState` was set to default.

How do I achieve the same tinting as default blendstate allows without switching to it?

Comment: Have you tried just doing a `new Color(12, 34, 56, 78)` ?

Comment: Well, this just gives me a different result. I actually get four different results with two blend states and two ways of creating colors. Guess I'll have to manually de-multiply each texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says about [Color.FromNonPremultiplied Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.fromnonpremultiplied.aspx): Converts a non-premultipled alpha color to a color that contains premultiplied alpha.

Based on this you should use either 
`BlendState.NonPremultiplied`and `Color(12, 34, 56, 78)`

OR

`BlendState.AlphaBlend` and `Color.FromNonPremultiplied(12, 34, 56, 78)`

together.